# How can I run a code after response is completed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, response, status

I'm working on a gem which needs to know when Rails response was completed and run a code base on it's status / body . Is there any way of doing this, without monkey patching Rails? Do you know some examples which could help me?

Comment: I think you want to build a piece of rack middleware.

Comment: [This RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware?view=asciicast) shows how to create a simple Rack Middleware. Be careful though when it comes to registering it with Rails - the RailsCast was made with Rails 2.3, so it is quite outdated in that part. The official [Rails on Rack guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#configuring-middleware-stack) can help you there.

Comment: I currently have a rack middleware which starts a websockets server. It's run before request, not after response. Now I want to observe each response (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html). But I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: OH, that's it! http://viget.com/extend/refactoring-patterns-the-rails-middleware-response-handler Thanks:).